# Monkey City Progress

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

I recently managed to have my computer infected by a virus, so I am wanting to do a complete re-install of windows.

One thing I don't want to lose is my progress on [Monkey City](http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Tower-Defense/Play/Bloons-Monkey-City.html). I've put a fair few hours in.

I always sign in to play, but I'm not confident that my progress is saved online.

Can someone confirm where my progress is saved, and if it is on my machine how can I back it up?

Answer (score 3):

Monkey city data is stored on the server which supplies the game.

After wiping my computer completely my data was still preserved after logging in.